# Highchart highlight area between points with custom colors

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a Highchart which displays earth and water pressure data (stored in the Database). I want to mark the area between the various points on x-axis with different colors which marks the type of area from where the data was collected. I have the color data (shown on top in a table) but I need to mark it on the chart

My chart looks as follows:
[image: Earth Water Pressure chart]

I want the chart to be viewed so as the background color from 284 to 285 is orange and from 285 to 286 is Pink and so on...

How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two possibilities:

- use [multicolor series](http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tg58gc6x/) `plugin`
- set extra serie and set [zones](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.areaspline.zones)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the render function provided like so

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]
        }]

    }, function (chart) { // on complete

        chart.renderer.rect(74, 0, 100, 300, 0)
            .attr({
                'stroke-width': 0,
                stroke: 'red',
                fill: 'yellow',
                zIndex: -1
            })
            .add();

    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z3jzjkke/

Comment: How can I get the X-Axis start and finish points? because theywill be required too. Also it's a width height based rectangle, can I get top left and bottom right?

Comment: The X-axis start is a little tricky but with a little bit of fiddling you can pull it from the svg that is created. Both x and y coords use the top left of the rectangle. You will have to fiddle around and find your heights and widths I'm afraid.